# How can I move Outlook Notes to (Mac) Entourage?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, entourage

I need to migrate a user's Outlook Notes from a PC to a Mac, which has Entourage installed on it.

Is there an easy way to do this that would get them into Entourage?  (Or at least into the Mac in a usable manner?)

Answer (score 0):

You can export them to a a tab-delimited text file. Click on Notes then `File->Import and Export...` Once you've exported the notes to a a tab-delimited text file file follow the directions here to import them into [Entourage](http://www.entourage.mvps.org/import_export/index.html)